# Not able to get the workspace_id with Watson Assistant

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ibm-watson

When trying to print workspace_id, it is printing None. And this affects my rest code.
I am using the IBM-Watson API for the first time and don't know much about it. I am stuck at the part where a workspace_id remains None.
All code files are attached herewith:

## service-credentials.json

```
{
    "discovery": {
        "url": "the_coorect_url",
        "apikey": "the_correct_apikey"
    },
    "assistant": {
         "url": "the_coorect_url",
         "apikey":"the_correct_apikey"
    }
}
```

## helper.py

```
import json
import watson_developer_cloud

def fetch_credentials(service_name, creds_file="service-credentials.json"):
    """Fetch credentials for cloud services from file.
    
    Params
    ======
    - service_name: a Watson service name, e.g. "discovery" or "conversation"
    - creds_file: file containing credentials in JSON format
    
    Returns
    =======
    creds: dictionary containing credentials for specified service
    """
    
    with open(creds_file, "r") as f:
        creds = json.load(f)
        return creds[service_name]


def fetch_object(service, obj_type, obj_name, create=False, create_args={}, **fetch_args):
    """Helper function to fetch objects from the Watson services.
    
    Params
    ======
    - service: a Watson service instance
    - obj_type: object type, one of: "environment", "configuration", "collection", "workspace"
    - obj_name: name used to look up / create object
    - create: whether to create object if not found (default: False)
    - create_args: arguments to pass in when creating, other than name
    - fetch_args: other arguments used to fetch object, e.g. environment_id
    
    Returns
    =======
    obj, obj_id: fetched object and its unique ID (for convenience)
    """

    # Methods for each object type
    list_methods = {
        "environment": "list_environments",
        "configuration": "list_configurations",
        "collection": "list_collections",
        "workspace": "list_workspaces"
    }
    get_methods = {
        "environment": "get_environment",
        "configuration": "get_configuration",
        "collection": "get_collection",
        "workspace": "get_workspace"
    }
    create_methods = {
        "environment": "create_environment",
        "configuration": "create_configuration",
        "collection": "create_collection",
        "workspace": "create_workspace"
    }
    
    # Look up by name
    obj = None
    obj_id = None
    obj_list = getattr(service, list_methods[obj_type])(**fetch_args)
    obj_list = obj_list.get_result()

    for o in obj_list[obj_type + "s"]:
        if o["name"] == obj_name:
            obj = o
            obj_id = obj[obj_type + "_id"]
            print("Found {}: {} ({})".format(obj_type, obj_name, obj_id))
            break
    
    if obj_id: # fetch object
        fetch_args[obj_type + "_id"] = obj_id
        obj = getattr(service, get_methods[obj_type])(**fetch_args)
        obj.get_result()
    elif create:  # create new, if desired
        if obj_type == "configuration":
            create_args["config_data"]["name"] = obj_name
        else:
            create_args["name"] = obj_name
            print(create_args)
        obj = getattr(service, create_methods[obj_type])(**create_args)
        obj = obj.get_result()
        obj_id = obj[obj_type + "_id"]
        obj = json.dumps(obj, indent=2)
        print("Created {}: {} ({})".format(obj_type, obj_name, obj_id))
    
    return obj, obj_id
```

In my Ipython notebook

## My_ipython.ipynb

```
!pip install --upgrade "ibm-watson>=CURRENT_API_VERSION"
import watson_developer_cloud
```

```
assistant_cred = helper.fetch_credentials('assistant')

assistant = watson_developer_cloud.AssistantV1(
                        version='2020-05-26',
                        url=assistant_cred['url'],
                        iam_apikey=assistant_cred['apikey'])

wrk, wrk_id = helper.fetch_object(assistant, "workspace", "Bookworm")
print(wrk_id)#Printing None(This is the issue)
print(wrk)#Printing None(This is the issue)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue getting this message
****'AttributeError: 'DiscoveryV1Adapter' object has no attribute 'list_workspace''****
It seems like Udacity has not upgraded the code since 2018 and at the same time, you are using the latest version of the watson_developer_cloud SDK package.
What to do is that you have to do it manually, you have to get the `wrk(obj) & wrk_id(obj_id)`.
go to `your workplace > Skills > your skill > Options > View API Details`. From the Skill Details page that opens, copy the Workspace ID and assign its value to the variable `wrk_id`, and copy the skill name and assign its value to the variable `wrk`.

I hope this works for you.
Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

The API has changed slightly in more recent versions of the SDKs.

I was able to get your example to run by removing all of the `.get_result()` references from your code.

For example, before was:

```
    # Look up by name
    obj = None
    obj_id = None
    obj_list = getattr(service, list_methods[obj_type])(**fetch_args)
    obj_list = obj_list.get_result()
```

and updated, working version uses:

```
    # Look up by name
    obj = None
    obj_id = None
    obj_list = getattr(service, list_methods[obj_type])(**fetch_args)
```

@moustafa-medhat-abdelwahap has a good suggestion as well.  Workspace names are not guaranteed to be unique.  You may want to consider storing the workspace ID in your local configuration.